# Arch linux: bash: rocminfo: command not found

Tags: arch-linux, amd-graphics, amd

I have fresh and updated arch linux install. I have AMD Radeon 7900 XTX.
I am trying to run stable diffusion and I installed these packages:

```
local/comgr 6.0.0-1
    Compiler support library for ROCm LLVM
local/hip-runtime-amd 6.0.0-1
    Heterogeneous Interface for Portability ROCm
local/hipblas 6.0.0-1
    ROCm BLAS marshalling library
local/hsa-rocr 6.0.0-2
    HSA Runtime API and runtime for ROCm
local/magma-hip 2.7.2-3
    Matrix Algebra on GPU and Multicore Architectures (with ROCm/HIP)
local/python-pytorch-rocm 2.2.0-2
    Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration (with ROCm)
local/python-torchvision-rocm 0.16.2-1
    Datasets, transforms, and models specific to computer vision (with ROCM support)
local/python-torchvision-rocm-debug 0.16.2-1
    Detached debugging symbols for python-torchvision-rocm
local/rccl 6.0.0-1
    ROCm Communication Collectives Library
local/rocalution 6.0.0-2
    Next generation library for iterative sparse solvers for ROCm platform
local/rocblas 6.0.0-1
    Next generation BLAS implementation for ROCm platform
local/rocfft 6.0.0-1
    Next generation FFT implementation for ROCm
local/rocm-clang-ocl 6.0.0-1
    OpenCL compilation with clang compiler
local/rocm-cmake 6.0.0-1
    CMake modules for common build tasks needed for the ROCm software stack
local/rocm-core 6.0.0-2
    AMD ROCm core package (version files)
local/rocm-dbgapi 6.0.0-1
    Support library necessary for a debugger of AMD's GPUs
local/rocm-device-libs 6.0.0-1
    ROCm Device Libraries
local/rocm-hip-libraries 6.0.0-1
    Develop certain applications using HIP and libraries for AMD platforms
local/rocm-hip-runtime 6.0.0-1
    Packages to run HIP applications on the AMD platform
local/rocm-hip-sdk 6.0.0-1
    Develop applications using HIP and libraries for AMD platforms
local/rocm-language-runtime 6.0.0-1
    ROCm runtime
local/rocm-llvm 6.0.0-2
    Radeon Open Compute - LLVM toolchain (llvm, clang, lld)
local/rocm-opencl-runtime 6.0.0-1
    OpenCL implementation for AMD
local/rocm-opencl-sdk 6.0.0-1
    Develop OpenCL-based applications for AMD platforms
local/rocm-smi-lib 6.0.0-1
    ROCm System Management Interface Library
local/rocminfo 6.0.0-1
    ROCm Application for Reporting System Info
local/rocrand 6.0.0-1
    Pseudo-random and quasi-random number generator on ROCm
local/rocsolver 6.0.0-1
    Subset of LAPACK functionality on the ROCm platform
local/rocsparse 6.0.0-1
    BLAS for sparse computation on top of ROCm
local/rocthrust 6.0.0-1
    Port of the Thrust parallel algorithm library atop HIP/ROCm
local/roctracer 6.0.0-1
    ROCm tracer library for performance tracing
local/tensorflow-amd-git 2.13-1
    Library for scalable machine learning (with ROCm)
```

But when I run `eocminfo` to check if rocm works I get this error:

```
me@archlinux ~> rocminfo
fish: Unknown command: rocminfo
```

How can I fix this ? Do I have to add some additional entry to my PATH variable ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

`rocminfo` is in `opt/rocm/bin/`. You can find this out by either checking the file list on https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/rocminfo/ below the "Package Contents" heading:

```
 Package Contents

    opt/
    opt/rocm/
    opt/rocm/bin/
    opt/rocm/bin/rocm_agent_enumerator
    opt/rocm/bin/rocminfo
```

or using `pacman -Ql rocminfo` after installing rocminfo.

So your intuition is correct, you need to add `/opt/rocminfo/bin` to PATH.